# Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given al registrar usuario

Tags: php, mysql, php7

```
include("conexion.php");


// Registrar

if(isset($_POST['registrar'])) {
    // no permitir que el usuario pueda ingresar sentencias sql (inyeccion sql)
    $nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['nombre']);
    $correo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['correo']);
    $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['user']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['pass']);

    // encriptar el password
    $password_encriptada = sha1($password);
    // para que no me permita duplicar la informacion

    $sql_user = "SELECT idusuarios FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario' ";

        // si se cargo bien la consulta
    if($sql_user){
        
        $query = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql_user);

        $filas = mysqli_num_rows($query);

        if($filas > 0) {
            echo "<script>
                            alert('El usuario ya existe');
                            window.location = 'index.php';
                        </script>";
        } else {
            $sql_usuario = "INSERT INTO usuarios(Nombre,Correo,Usuario,Password)
                                            VALUES ('$nombre','$correo','$usuario','$password_encriptada')";
            
            $resultadoUsuario = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql_usuario);

            if ($resultadoUsuario > 0) {
                echo "<script>
                                alert('Registro Exitoso');
                                window.location = 'index.php';
                            </script>";
            } else {
                echo "<script>
                                alert('Error al registrarse');
                                window.location = 'index.php';
                            </script>";
            }

        }

    } else {
         echo mysqli_error($conexion);
    }
}
```

Estoy tratando de registrar un usuario nuevo al cual, por más que ya existe, lo sigue creando.

El error me lo da en la linea de `$filas = mysqli_num_rows($query);`, también intenté hacerlo de esta forma `$filas = $query->num:rows` pero me tira el mismo error.

En donde me dice:

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in.

Comment: En algunos casos `mysqli_real_escape_string` no te protege contra inyección SQL ([ver esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/5587982)). Deberías usar consultas preparadas. Además de más seguras, son más claras, y más rápidas en el caso de que tengas que repetir varias veces una misma consulta con datos distintos. Si usas consultas preparadas no haría falta usar `mysqli_real_escape_string`. En la comunidad de programadores de PHP el estándar es usar consultas preparadas para casos como estos. Saludos.

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que estas intentando contar las filas de una consulta que no trajo resultados. pára resolver esto debes comprobar que el resultado del `mysqli_query` no sea `false`, te sugiero modificar el if de `if($sql_user){` para usarlo cómo comprobación de la ejecución del metodo `mysqli_query` así:

```
include("conexion.php");


// Registrar

if(isset($_POST['registrar'])) {
    // no permitir que el usuario pueda ingresar sentencias sql (inyeccion sql)
    $nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['nombre']);
    $correo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['correo']);
    $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['user']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['pass']);

    // encriptar el password
    $password_encriptada = sha1($password);
    // para que no me permita duplicar la informacion

    $sql_user = "SELECT idusuarios FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario' ";

        // Compruebo si la consulta es válida y trae resultados.
    if($query = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql_user)){

        $filas = mysqli_num_rows($query);

        if($filas > 0) {
            echo "<script>
                            alert('El usuario ya existe');
                            window.location = 'index.php';
                        </script>";
        } else {
            $sql_usuario = "INSERT INTO usuarios(Nombre,Correo,Usuario,Password)
                                            VALUES ('$nombre','$correo','$usuario','$password_encriptada')";

            $resultadoUsuario = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql_usuario);

            if ($resultadoUsuario > 0) {
                echo "<script>
                                alert('Registro Exitoso');
                                window.location = 'index.php';
                            </script>";
            } else {
                echo "<script>
                                alert('Error al registrarse');
                                window.location = 'index.php';
                            </script>";
            }

        }

    } else {
         echo mysqli_error($conexion);
    }
}
```

Espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: Graciassssssssssssss